# How can I determine a web page's visibility?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom, browser

I want to spare browsers from unnecessarily acquiring resources when my web page is shown in a non-active tab or hidden by another program window (= inactive).

Which events to I need to subscribe to in order to recognize when my web page is (in)active, or (in)visible?

Answer (score 1):

document.hidden ?

Try minimizing your browser and see the logs:

```
setInterval(function(){console.log(document.hidden)},2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying the help! :) The above mentioned Page Visibility API seems to be what I'm looking for.